# Using static on typedef struct

Tags: c, static, struct, typedef

I use the following code a lot in C:

```
typedef struct
  {
  int member;
  } structname;
```

Now i'm trying to keep that struct definition local to a particular source file, so that no other source file even knows the struct exists.  I tried the following:

```
static typedef struct
  {
  int member;
  } structname;
```

but GCC whines because of an illegal access specifier.  Is it even possible to keep a struct's declaration private to a source file?

Comment: It's not "whining", dude.  It's a *syntax error*.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you declare the typedef struct within a .c file, it will be private for that source file.

If you declare this typedef in a .h file, it will be accesible for all the .c files that include this header file.

Your statement:

```
static typedef struct
```

Is illegal since you are not declaring a variable or function.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't put all my code in the second time. Edited my post to fix this

Comment: Its still illegal my friend.  static can be used only to declare a variable or a function, not to define a new type.  static and typefef don't go together.

Answer (score 5):

A structure definition is private to a source file unless placed in a shared header file. No other source file can access the members of the struct, even if given a pointer to the struct (since the layout is not known in the other compilation unit).

If the struct needs to be used elsewhere, it must be used only as a pointer. Put a forward declaration of the form `struct structname; typedef struct structname structname;` in the headerfile, and use `structname *` everywhere else in your codebase. Then, since the structure members appear only in one source file, the structure's contents are effectively 'private' to that file.

Comment: This confuses me. Are you saying it must be used as a pointer even if it's in the header file?

Comment: @Aerovistae: if it *is* in the header file, then it isn't private, and can be used fully by any file that includes the header file.

Comment: I posted a question about this so as not to get bogged down with a long comment exchange, if you're interested in answering-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933144/how-do-structs-behave-in-terms-of-visibility-to-other-files

Answer (score 5):

All declarations are always local to a particular translation unit in C.  That's why you need to include headers in all source files that intend to use a given declaration.

If you want to restrict the use of your `struct`, either declare it in the file in which you use it, or create a special header that only your file includes.

Answer (score 1):

Hernan Velasquez's answer is the correct answer: there are *several* problems with your code snippet.  Here's a counter-example:

```
/* This should go in a .h if you will use this typedef in multiple .c files */
typedef struct {
  int a;
  char b[8];
} mystructdef;

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /* "static" is legal when you define the variable ...
    ... but *not* when you declare the typedef */
  static mystructdef ms;
```