# How do structs behave in terms of visibility to other files?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is taken from an answer to a different question on SO:

> A structure definition is private to a source file unless placed in a
>   shared header file. No other source file can access the members of the
>   struct, even if given a pointer to the struct (since the layout is not
>   known in the other compilation unit).
>
> If the struct needs to be used elsewhere, it must be used only as a
>   pointer. Put a forward declaration of the form struct structname;
>   typedef struct structname structname; in the headerfile, and use
>   structname * everywhere else in your codebase. Then, since the
>   structure members appear only in one source file, the structure's
>   contents are effectively 'private' to that file.

This confuses me. Why can you only use pointers to a struct even if you include a header file that declares it (but does not define it)?

I mean, if I include a header that declares a function, a function which is defined in a separate implementation file, I can still access that function-- why are structs different? Why are their members private even if you can get to the declaration?

Comment: If you include the header with the struct definition, you are not restricted to using only pointers to the struct. But a header with only a struct declaration is unusual, because you can say `struct Foo` whenever you want. You don't need a header for that.

Comment: I mean if you include the header with just the struct declaration.

Comment: Fair enough. Because a pointer does not need a complete type. You can only do things that do not require a complete type. But as I said, it is unusual to have a header with a struct declaration and no definition.

Comment: The text you quoted is not very well written. Bear in mind that "header files" are only separate before preprocessing; after preprocessing there is only translation units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with visibilty. The quote is referring to a struct *forward declaration* (so, no definition available)

The header effectively contains something like :

```
struct X;  // No definition available
```

A forward declaration introduces an *incomplete type*. There are very few things you can do with an incomplete type, but one of them is declaring a pointer (not dereferencing it).

As long as the compiler doesn't know the size of the struct, or it's members (it certainly can't with a simple forward declaration), it won't allow any declaration of an `X`, nor any dereferencing of a pointer to an `X`.